# open chrome developer tools inside popup

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to open the developer tools inside(attached to) a popup and not detached? I'm currently working a site with popups and need to bebug javascript and find it quite annoying to toggle between the popup and the developer tools window.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422214/how-can-i-inspect-disappearing-element-in-a-browser

Answer (score 6):

When debugging popup windows you can convert them to tabs. You can do this by `right-clicking` the `title icon` and selecting the `show as tab` option. Then you can open the `developer console` as usual.

Answer (score 3):

- Open Chrome Dev Tools (Cmd + Option + I)
- Open the Console tab
- Paste the following, the hit enter:

```js
setTimeout(function(){debugger;}, 5000)
```

Navigate to your popup and wait- in 5 seconds, the debugger will pause the page, and you can see your code!
Enjoy your debugging!

[Reference from Mitch Winkel-Davis](https://medium.com/@mitchwd/debugging-popups-modals-animations-e833856d80a9)

Answer (score -2):

1. Please press and hold the tiny button for seconds.
   After that, you will find the another icon (or button) at the same location.
2. Please release your mouse button.
   You can see a popup window of developer tools.

Comment: I don't know what tiny button you mean. A popup has by default no buttons, besides the OS default ones to alter the window and the address bar. I open the dev tools with `CMD+ALT+J` (on osx). The _docking_ feature is not available for popups.

Answer (score -3):

Just press `⌥ + cmd + I` when the pop up window is in focus and dev tools will open in a new pop up window