# How can I inspect disappearing element in a browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, firebug, opera-dragonfly

**How can I inspect an element which disappears when my mouse moves away?**
[image: Example dropdown which disappears]

I don't know its ID, class or anything but want to inspect it.

**Solutions I have tried:**

Run jQuery selector inside console `$('*:contains("some text")')` but didn't have any luck mainly because the element is not hidden but probably removed from the DOM tree.

Manually inspecting DOM tree for changes gives me nothing as it seems to be just too fast to notice what have changed.

**SUCCESS:**

I have been successful with Event breakpoints. Specifically - mousedown in my case. Just go to `Sources-> Event Listener Breakpoints-> Mouse-> mousedown` in Chrome. After that I clicked the element I wanted to inspect and inside `Scope Variables` I saw some useful directions.

Comment: Your question helped although I did not get on the breakpoint using the sources, I executed the following script in the console: `document.body.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
  debugger;
})` That got me in a break and I could inspect the elements created.

Comment: You rock. Had this exact issue with a React-Select control, where I couldn't view the HTML of the list items because the subtree would delete any time I'd click away. Needed the item ID's in order to automate clicks using Selenium. Thanks!

Answer (score 303, accepted):

<s>(This answer only applies to Chrome Developer Tools.</s> See update below.)

Find an element that contains the disappearing element. Right click on the element and apply "Break on... > Subtree Modifications." This will throw a debugger pause before the element disappears, which will allow you to interact with the element in a paused state.

[image]

**Update Oct 22 2019:** with the release of v. 70, it looks like FireFox finally supports this kind of debugging [2](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/10/firefox-70-a-bountiful-release-for-all/) [3](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/Break_on_DOM_mutation):

[image]

**Update Sep 15 2020:** Chrome has an "Emulate a focused page" option (you can get it from the [⌘]+[P] Command Menu, or Global Preferences) for this exact need. [5 - h/t @sulco on Twitter](https://twitter.com/sulco/status/1305841873945272321)

Comment: To avoid some possible confusion - the debugger will pause as you're triggering the event, a.k.a. typing in a place name. When the screen pauses just hit the play button on the DOM itself and you'll be able to trigger the event.

Comment: This doesn't work if the page has captured the right-click and does it's own thing on right-click.

Comment: This doesn't work for the first of two dialogs in the same container

Comment: @Still_learning Can you explain what you mean by "two dialogs in the same container."

Comment: `<v-container><v-dialog></v-dialog><v-dialog></v-dialog></v-container>` - in my case the first dialog only displays until the data arrives from the db, approx 1 second

Comment: This is the best way to handle not just such "disappearing elements" but also to inspect dom changes which in turn will lead you to the problematic section. Just ensure that you apply this on the deepest section where you know for sure the issue lies

Comment: This didn't work for me - using react, and the dom element that was appearing was a popover that was a direct child of <body>

Answer (score 175):

1. Open console
2. Type in `setTimeout(()=>{debugger;},5000);`
3. Press Enter

Now you have 5 seconds to make your element appears. Once it appeared, wait until the debugger hits. As long as you don't resume, you can play with your element and it won't disappear.

---

Useful tip to avoid repeating those steps above every time:

add this as a bookmarklet:

1. Bookmark any page
2. Edit this new bookmark
3. Replace the URL/location with: `javascript:(function(){setTimeout(()=>{debugger;},5000);})();`

Next time you wish to use this, just click/tap this bookmark.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  (The "F8" solve in multiple other answers here did not work.)

Comment: It works like magic even with "powered by google" dropdown suggestions. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 154):

An alternative method in Chrome:

- Open devTools (F12).
- Select the "Sources" tab.
- While the element you want is displayed, press F8 (or Ctrl+/). *This will break script execution* and "freeze" the DOM exactly as it is displayed.
- From this point, use Ctrl+Shift+C to select the element.

Comment: I noticed this only works when you have the developer tools already opened in the 'Sources' tab.

Comment: it does freeze the code from execution but the element still disappeared (I'm using React).

Comment: My Chrome says F8 or Crtl + \ (not Crtl + /). Also, the Crtl + \ doesn't work in my case...

Comment: This does *not* work on Google video control pop-ups... the control appears to fade from view as soon as you hit the key, and has completely faded out before the freeze occurs.

Comment: This isn't working at all... the element still disappears. I'm using Vue - maybe it doesn't align with Chrome developer tools?

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore - my current chrome version is : 80.0.3987.149. I remember this use to work about a year ago 

Comment: Didn't work for me for `react-day-picker`'s `<DayPickerInput />`

Answer (score 86):

**Verified in 2022**

Do the following:

1. Open the console and navigate to Elements tab
2. Type `command + shift + P` (OSX) or `control + shift + P` (Windows)
3. Type the word `focused`
4. Select `Emulate a focused page` from the the menu

Now clicking around in the console will not close the element.

Comment: Absolutely awesome - thanks @dipole_moment - this is why I find myself scrolling to the bottom answers first in stackoverflow now - better current solutions

Comment: As an alternative to opening the "run command" pop-up box with Command-Shift-P or Ctrl-Shift-P, you can go under the Dev Tools' three-dots menu, under More Tools, and click Rendering.

Comment: saved me !!!!!. can you please explain what its really doing in browser?

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Worked in Chrome in 2023 as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

I am using chrome on Mac there I've followed above steps but I'll try to explain a bit more:

1. Right click and go to inspect element.
2. Go to sources tab.
3. Then hover on the element.
4. Then using keyboard `F8` **or** `Command(Window) \`. It will pause the screen in a static state and the element won't disappear on hover out.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, for the detailed instructions! After a show of extreme dexterity - clicking a button, pressing `Ctr + Shift + C`, moving the mouse to hover over the element, and pressing `F8` within the space of a second and a half - I finally got my element in inspectable mode

Answer (score 5):

The `Emulate a focused page` feature is the best way to inspect disappearing elements. After enabling this feature, pop-ups will not disappear.

As of **May 2023**, Chrome has relocated the menu item for this feature.  Please see the screenshot below to find it. The feature can be found in the 9th option of the "Rendering" pane.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Firebug there are different solutions for this:

1. You can use [Break On Mutate](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Break_On_Mutate) inside the HTML panel. (with this you'll also be able to find out which element it is)
2. You can right-click the element and choose *Inspect Element with Firebug*

Also you may want to follow [issue 551](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=551), which asks for a way to temporarily block specific events.

**Edit:**

To find out which element it is you can also enable the [HTML panel options](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Options_Menu) *Highlight Changes*, *Expand Changes* and *Scroll Changes Into View* to make the element visible inside the HTML panel.

Sebastian

Comment: Chrome as well has decent inspector. The problem is - right click on element makes it disappear in my case. Chrome also has Break on DOM mutate. The problem with this - I don't know which element it is as it's dynamically generated

Comment: I just edited my answer to give a hint how to get to know which element it is.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used **Expand recursively** option on google chrome:

The steps are:

1. Inspect the dropdown field
2. Find the dynamic DOM (the purple highlight)
3. Right-mouse click on that dynamic DOM
4. Choose **Expand recursively**: 
   [image]
5. We can see all elements are there

Here is a demo:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hover over the element with your mouse and press F8 (this in Chrome) to pause the script execution. The hover state will remain in visible to you.

It take you to the sources tab.
Go back to Elements tab. This time code will not disapper.

Comment: My component disappears as soon as I hit F8, before the pause takes hold.

Answer (score 1):

There Could be Dom element and the controller functions fighting at to refresh the session. Running the application by "Start without debugging" helped in my case.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/085BA.png)

Answer (score 1):

##### I've written an [article](https://dev.to/yaireo/css-debugging-disappearing-elements-lhj) about debugging CSS of disappearing elements

Using hotkeys to automatically go into `debugger` mode with hotkeys keyboard shortcut:

---

1. Install the [shortkeys](https://www.shortkeys.app/) extension
2. Click on the extension icon and chose "options":
   [image: click shortkeys options menu]
3. Configure as follows:
   [image: List item]
4. Click *"Save shortcuts"* button (bottom-right)

Now, go to any page, make sure devtools is opened, and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> keys, while your inspection target element is visible.

---

I'm using *Windows OS* and this hotkeys combination is good for me and is not "taken" by any other shortcut, but of course, you can choose any other.

Answer (score 0):

you can view the elements appearing and disappearing in the inspector under elements. If you navigate to the element when it is visible you should be able to see it disappear or see its css change when it status changes.

This is possible with firebug in firefox or the built inspector in chrome.

Comment: Yes. I have stated that changes happen too fast in DOM and page modifies DOM heavily so it's really not a solution as I am not able distinguish my needed elements from a bunch of modifications everywhere :)

Comment: you could try tracing what is going on using console.log e.g. at the beginning of the function you are trying to check you can view object css  etc. Or slow down the changes until you know they work properly and then change the speed to what you want it to be e.g. hide('slow') in jquery

Comment: Problem is - it's not my own codebase, it's a legacy, big, old, codebase where simple search through the files gives me nothing.. :)

Comment: you can view what files are being used by the page in the inspector too. I would go through removing them until it breaks then look in the file that broke it and go from there. You can always search the actual files too.

Comment: Great point. Done that too. Found obfuscated JS code. Lots of it. It's no a project of mine, nor the original source files are present. So pretty much these methods simply fail. Prettyfind didn't produce any sensible results aswell. Seems like JS was generated with Google Closure tool

Comment: does this help: http://www.madxperts.com/2011/07/23/de-obfuscate-javascript-code-two-clicks/

Comment: Chrome has built in prettyfier. Tried that too, but the code seems to be very optimized and advanced(read: unreadable). What I would like - maybe disable mouse events. For example when I right click on the disappearing element, it should let me inspect the element but not report the page about the event

Comment: how about this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213703/how-do-i-view-events-fired-on-an-element-in-chrome-web-developer

Comment: Thanks for this URL. I have also found my element with mouse breakpoints(mousedown). So this helps too :)

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem but i use Firefox it disappear as soon as i open inspect element found a solution:
open the 4 dashes(settings) go to web developer > Debugger and immediately press F8 which is the shortcut for the pause that stop the script before it kick and detect that you opened the developers tools