# Not able to inspect an element path in kendo multiselect

Tags: javascript, automation, webdriver-io, kendo-multiselect

I have a kendo-multiselect drop-down I need to automate.

When I click on it, the drop-down with multiple entries opens. But, if I right click on those and click on inspect, it gets closed and I am not able to see the element path.

I want to get the element path so as to automate it using WebdriverIO.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use some extension like selectorsHub, it'll make your job way easier while picking up selectors

Comment: But the element itself is not visible in the DOM. Only once i select an element from the list , then only its visible in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, but I've had problems with most on certain libraries, so you have to test them out yourself. I don't have access to  `kendo-multiselect`.

---

**A.** Call the debugger (`F8`|`CTRL+/`) from the console with a timeout delay. This will give you `<timeout>` milliseconds to inspect your drop-down element and wait for the debugger to block execution.

**Steps:**

1. Open your browser console (Chrome used for testing)
2. Type your command: `setTimeout(() => { debugger; }, 10000);`
3. Now you have 10 seconds to select your drop-down
4. Wait for `debugger` to start, then inspect your drop-down elements

---

**B.** Using ChromeDevTool's `Emulate a focused page` [option](https://www.algolia.com/doc/ui-libraries/autocomplete/guides/debugging/). This has only worked for me sporadically.

[image: CDT: Emulate a focused page]

---

You have to try it out until you find the options that work for you. Here are several other [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422214/how-can-i-inspect-disappearing-element-in-a-browser) to try. Good luck!