# selecting Dropdown option using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, drop-down-menu, ui-automation

I'm trying to fill this form and can't really select the dropdown options, link
https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/admin/saveSystemUser

I also can't use select because there is no select tag in the HTML code

```
user_role = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]"))
user_role.select_by_visible_text("Admin")
```

this shows an error that select cant be used on a div tag

Comment: Which is the drop down you are trying to interact with. Mention the steps to navigate to that page and find that drop down element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drop down element is not build with `Select` tag, so `Select` library cannot be used to interact with the drop down.

Also the options are disappearing while trying to inspect them. Refer [How can I inspect disappearing element in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34095731/16452840)

Below is the code where I was able click on `Admin` option.

```
# Imports for Explicit waits
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login")

# to navigate to the Add user page.
time.sleep(20)

# find all the elements for the drop down
select_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//i[contains(@class,'oxd-select-text--arrow')]")

# click on the first drop down
select_elements[0].click()

# Locate the Admin option from the drop down
admin_option = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@role='listbox']//span[text()='Admin']")))
admin_option.click()
```